# How to make an active JFrame with an infinite loop in the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to make the application start unpacking the archive in a separate thread, but before that a JFrame with a progress bar would appear.  It would be fully active during unpacking, but at the same time that code in the main thread will be executed after unpacking (for this I want to use an infinite loop that will stop after unpacking)
 How can this be effectively, correctly implemented?

Comment: "an infinite loop that will stop after unpacking". Infinite loops don't stop. Period. that's what makes them "infinite".

Comment: try Sun's/Oracle's tutorial [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (uses `SwingWorker`)